# Joomla, online image editing

Tags: image-processing, joomla

I've been asked to do a site in Joomla. It must feature a way for visitors and administrators to upload and resize/crop images online.
Can anyone give me a hint of where to start?

I'm using Joomla 3.0.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking through this extension category:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/images/image-management

If you don't like any of those you'll need to find a javascript image editor that you like and then wrap it in your own Joomla extension.

Answer (score 1):

RokGallery does everything but I'm not sure about letting unregistered guests upload image. You'll have to look into that one.

http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokgallery